# Failed to resolve: :tslocationmanager:

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, build.gradle

I've had issues syncing my project in Android Studio regarding 'react-native-background-geolocation' package.

> Failed to resolve: :tslocationmanager:

Running ./gradlew :app:dependencies gives the following error:

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration 
':app:_debugApkCopy'.
   > Could not find :tslocationmanager:.
     Required by:
         MyAppName:app:unspecified
         MyAppName:app:unspecified > MyAppName:react-native-background-geolocation:unspecified
```

I've following the installation instructions outlined  [here](https://github.com/transistorsoft/react-native-background-geolocation/blob/master/help/INSTALL-ANDROID-RNPM.md) to no avail.

Relevant project-level build.gradle:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        maven {
           url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
        maven {
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native-background-geolocation/android/libs"
        }
        maven {
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native-background-fetch/android/libs"
        }
    }
}
```

And the relevant app-level build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile "com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0"
    compile project(':react-native-background-geolocation')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    compile "me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.19@aar"
    compile(name: 'tslocationmanager', ext: 'aar')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`tslocationmanager` is part of `react-native-background-geolocation` - and most likely does not need to be directly referenced - replace `compile(name: 'tslocationmanager', ext: 'aar')` with `compile project(':react-native-background-fetch')`. see their [GitHub](https://github.com/transistorsoft/react-native-background-geolocation/blob/master/help/INSTALL-ANDROID.md).

Comment: I have the license key enabled and have gone through that portion of the setup. Removing that particular compile doesn't get rid of the error.

Comment: @FnxPL123 this does a) not provide any logical sense and b) the documentation does not include it either. you're missing the `compile project(':react-native-background-fetch')`.

Comment: it was left over from another dev who was probably trying to resolve the same issue. Doesn't seem to be the cause of the error either way. I included the compile statement you listed (as well as some config data that I didn't put into MainApplication.java) and the error remains.